# How can I make an event for the Layout (exept some elements) in SilverLight or Windows Phone

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I have a form with two text boxes, what event and how can I use to get an action when I click the Layout, exept this textboxes? So when I click on the textboxes this event should not be work. It should work when I click on the other parts of the layout,exept the textboxes that I have on the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a MouseLeftButtonUp-event on the main Grid in your Page. Something like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" MouseLeftButtonUp="LayoutRoot_MouseLeftButtonUp">
```

And the event looks like this:

```
private void LayoutRoot_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //Do something
}
```

I tested this on a page with two TextBoxes and a Checkbox and this works. Everywhere I click except for the TextBoxes and the CheckBox the event is raised. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I have done something similar to this. In the code behind I used this:

```
layoutRoot.AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler((s, e) =>
                {
                    //In this case, don't focus.
                    if (RecieveFocus != null && 
                        e.OriginalSource is Textbox &&
                        ((e.OriginalSource as Textbox).Tag == "DONT FOCUS")
                    {
                        //do nothing, or whatever you want
                    }
                    else if(RecieveFocus != null)
                        RecieveFocus(this, new EventArgs());                            
                }), true);
```

You can check to see if your original source is the text box, and if so don't do whatever you wish to do otherwise. The last boolean true there for Add Handler says to handle events marked as already handled.

I made an event called RecieveFocus that I handle and raise that even if anything is clicked on my layout root except for (in this case) the textbox with a tag "DONT FOCUS"